# How is it possible for a Javascript function to be undefined and still invokeable?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

When I write

```
window.external.AddSearchProvider
```

in Internet Explorer 11 I get "undefined", but I can still call and use the function. While in Chrome the method is defined and usable.

If I write

```
"AddSearchProvider" in window.external
```

I get "true" in both Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Is this the expected behavior? I was under the impression I could check if I could use a function by checking if it was defined, or is it something I have misunderstood?

Comment: Functions can't be `undefined` because they are functions, but variables can be `undefined` before holding the `function` object.

Comment: false!  `AddSearchProvider` is a variable in `window.external`.  `in` checks if there is a variable within 'window.external' with that name.  the value of `AddSearchProvider` doesn't matter

Comment: @Thouartamazing huh?  It sure seems odd to me that the value of `window.external.AddSearchProvider` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.external.AddSearchProvider` is not a "plain" javascript function. It's a native function provided by the browser and each browser handle it differently.

When you type `window.external.AddSearchProvider` in the browser javascript console, you see the representation of this value in the javascript of the browser. Most browser implements a representation of their native function, but it seems like Internet Explorer does not, so you see an `undefined` because the console has no value to display. But the function is callable.

As a example, you can see it as an object with a method like this

```
toJavascriptValue : function() {
    return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in
says

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.

`Addsearchprovider` is a variable in `window.external`.  `in` checks if there is a variable within `window.external` with that name.  the value of `AddSearchProvider` doesn't matter

window.external.AddSearchProvider() is a trigger. it triggers all the window.external.AddSearchProvider events that are assigned.

window.external.AddSearchProvider() and window.external.AddSearchProvider are completely different.

Comment: If the property value is `undefined` then how is it possible to issue a function call (successfully) to `window.external.AddSearchProvider()`?

Comment: window.external.AddSearchProvider() triggers all window.external.AddSearchProvider events assigned in page, which in this case is nothing.

Comment: document.getElementById("div").click() triggers a click event on div.

Comment: What does that have to do with `AddSearchProvider`?

Comment: window.external.AddSearchProvider() is a trigger. it triggers all the window.external.AddSearchProvider events that are assigned.  window.external.AddSearchProvider() and window.external.AddSearchProvider are completely different.